# Microsoft UWP store Subscription management without API?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Does Microsoft Windows&Xbox Partner Center not provide any portal to manage subscriptions and ad-on purchases ? I cannot see any report or overview like Google Play Store Console has. 
For example, on google play store I am able to search and find by Order ID and I can see the status of a subscription. I can see how many subscriptions are cancelled and how many are active?
What is the best way to get this information? 
For example, if a user complains about his subscription status, how can i help him?

I can only find an information regarding this whole Api implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-4

And most of the people dont even understand it as I see so many open question. I have already spent significant time reading and trying to understand whole this process. 
If I understand correctly, We need to implement a backend Api and Api should generate Accesstoken and send to the App and app should generate a User ID but this has to be done **from User's PC** directly as he is logged in on his machine with his account. That means that my new version of the app has to implement it first and published. Thus i can start collecting information in the background. Wow is that really how supposed to work?  (see the diagram below)

[image]

Can someone from Microsoft clarify this? Basically if i understand correctly Microsoft tells us, sell something and forget about it. Don't manage it. If you want manage it, program more and start collecting in the background. Do I understand it well? if yes, Why?

Answer (score 1):

For subscription Add-ons, if you want to manage it in the service, you could check these documents: [Get subscriptions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user) and [Change the billing state of a subscription for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/change-the-billing-state-of-a-subscription-for-a-user). These documents show how to manage subscriptions from your services.
And if you want to manage products from service, the document you mentioned is the correct document. It is required to create an Azure AD.

If you want to manage subscription Add-ons in your app, please refer to this document:[Enable subscription add-ons for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app).